# How can I stop getting suggestions for a specific group?

Tags: meetup

Meetup.com is useful, but it never forgets anything, even when I tell it to.

If I mark down an interest and then later remove it, or if I join a group and then leave it, or even if I just look at the group's page too often, Meetup will use that data over and over again to make totally useless suggestions for meetups that I will never actually go to, either because I don't want to go to meetups for that interest, or because I'm not eligible to join the group.

Is there any way to stop Meetup.com from suggesting a specific group, or from using a specific interest wastefully to suggest groups?

Comment: I wish they'd support that, meditative yoga chakra balancing and transvestite coders are groups I have no interest in. They always clutter up views on meetup. I'd rather make room for other suggestions to flow through

Comment: Somebody should build a dedicated chrome extension for this.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a browser extension like [TaperMonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo) for Chrome or [GreaseMonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) for Firefox, you can run some quick JavaScript every time `https://www.meetup.com/` is run and delete any items against your blacklisted criteria.

Assuming you wanted to hide the following groups:

```
https://www.meetup.com/GroupWithDailyMeetups
https://www.meetup.com/SpammyGroup
```

Then just take the two group names and add them to the blacklist in the script below

```
var blacklist = ["GroupWithDailyMeetups", SpammyGroup];
var blRegex = new RegExp(blacklist.join("|"));
$("a").filter(function(i,el) { return (blRegex.test(el.href)); })
      .closest("li.event-listing")
      .remove();
```

Comment: I used Kyle script from GitHub: https://github.com/KyleMit/CustomizeTheWeb/blob/master/Scripts/FilterMeetup.js